# how to use nvidia vdpau decoding for mplayer video player in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, nvidia, mplayer

How can I manage to switch on nvidia vdpau decoding on mplayer video player in Ubuntu 11.04? It doesn't work with default options. I've got the proprietary drivers installed:

```
dpkg -l nvidia-current 
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                                  Version                                               Description
+++-=====================================================-=====================================================-==========================================================================================================================
ii  nvidia-current                                        270.41.06-0ubuntu1                                    NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
```

If I try it like this:

```
mplayer -vo vdpau and -vc ffh264vdpau,ffmpeg12vdpau,ffwmv3vdpau,ffvc1vdpau -ao alsa file.mp4
```

I get sound but no image window, the prompt showing this:

```
Playing file.mp4.
libavformat file format detected.
[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0
[lavf] stream 1: audio (aac), -aid 0, -alang und
VIDEO:  [H264]  832x468  24bpp  25.000 fps  1402.1 kbps (171.2 kbyte/s)
Clip info:
 major_brand: isom
 minor_version: 512
 compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
 encoder: Lavf52.64.2
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
Error opening/initializing the selected video_out (-vo) device.
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [faad] AAC (MPEG2/4 Advanced Audio Coding)
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 94.7 kbit/6.17% (ratio: 11841->192000)
Selected audio codec: [faad] afm: faad (FAAD AAC (MPEG-2/MPEG-4 Audio))
==========================================================================
AO: [alsa] 48000Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
Video: no video
Starting playback...
A:  39.2 (39.2) of 5341.1 ( 1:29:01.0)  2.9%
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `-vo vdpau` and `-vc ffh264vdpau,ffmpeg12vdpau,ffwmv3vdpau,ffvc1vdpau,` command line options or put them in `~/.mplayer/config`.

Comment: edited that I tried it like the following but get no image: mplayer -vo vdpau and -vc ffh264vdpau,ffmpeg12vdpau,ffwmv3vdpau,ffvc1vdpau -ao alsa file.mp4

Comment: Do you have the proprietary nvidia drivers installed?

Comment: edited I've got them installed

Comment: @avilella: Well this is a Xorg/nvidia issue then and not an mplayer problem.